# A list that never invalidates iterators

Tags: c++, linked-list, pointers

I need a forward list with iterators that can survive anything – from removal of pointed element to destroying whole list. I decided to implement this with shared pointers, each node in the list stores a `std::shared_ptr` to the next node and iterators have their own pointer to a given node. I think that makes all accessible data safe.
All the snippets are part of a single file as the naming will be refactored before splitting into .hpp/.cpp files.

[Demo](https://ideone.com/O6VD3N) 
Ps. Code requires some of C++17 features, so a somehow recent compiler is required.

**INCLUDES**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
```

**NODE**

```
template<class T, template<class> class shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr>
struct Node {
    using shared_ptr_t = shared_ptr<Node<T>>;

    shared_ptr_t next;
    T value;

    Node(shared_ptr_t n, const T& v) {
        value = v;
        next = n;
    }
};
```

**ITERATOR**

```
template<class T>
class iterator {
public:
    using shared_ptr_t = typename Node<T>::shared_ptr_t;
    using node_t = Node<T>;

    iterator(shared_ptr_t node) {
        m_node = node;
    }
    bool operator==(const iterator& it) const { return m_node == it.m_node; }
    bool operator!=(const iterator& it) const { return !(it == *this); }

    bool valid() const {
        return bool(m_node);
    }
    T& operator*() const {
        return m_node->value;
    }
    shared_ptr_t node() const {
        return m_node;
    }
    void insert(const T& value) const {
        if(m_node) {
            m_node->next = std::make_shared<node_t>(m_node->next, value);
        } else {
            throw std::logic_error{"Invalid iterator can't insert"};
        }
    }
    shared_ptr_t next(const iterator& it) const {
        return std::exchange(m_node->next, it.m_node);
    }

    iterator& operator++() {
        m_node = m_node->next;
        return *this;
    }
    iterator& advance(int dist) {
        while(dist-- > 0 && m_node) {
            ++(*this);
        }
        return *this;
    }
    void swap(iterator& it) {
        std::swap(m_node, it.m_node);
    }

    template<class>
    friend class List;

private:
    shared_ptr_t m_node;
};
```

**LIST**

```
template<class T>
class List {
public:
    using shared_ptr_t = typename Node<T>::shared_ptr_t;
    using iterator_t = iterator<T>;
    using node_t = Node<T>;

    List() = default;
    explicit List(const List& list) {
        this->operator=(list);
    }
    explicit List(List&& list) {
        this->operator=(std::forward(list));
    }
    explicit List(iterator_t&& fwd_it, size_t explicit_size = 0) {
        m_size = explicit_size;
        m_root = std::exchange(fwd_it.m_node, nullptr);

        if(!m_size) {
            for(auto it = begin(); it.valid(); ++it) {
                ++m_size;
            }
        }
    }
    explicit List(const iterator_t& begin, const iterator_t& end = iterator_t{nullptr}) {
        auto it = begin;
        while(it.valid() && it != end) {
            push_back(*it);
            ++it;
        }
    }

    List<T>& operator=(const List& list) {
        clear();
        for(auto& el: list) {
            push_back(el);
        }

        m_size = list.size();
        return *this;
    }
    List<T>& operator=(List&& list) {
        m_root = std::exchange(list.m_root, nullptr);
        m_size = std::exchange(list.m_size, 0);
        return *this;
    }

    size_t size() const {
        return m_size;
    }

    void insert(const size_t idx, const T& value) {
        bound_check(bound_check_type::GREATER, "List<T>::insert(idx)", idx);

        auto it = begin();

        if(idx != 0) {
            it.advance(static_cast<int>(idx) - 1);
            it.insert(value);
        } else {
            m_root = std::make_shared<node_t>(it.node(), value);
        }

        ++m_size;
    }
    void push_back(const T& val) {
        insert(m_size, val);
    }
    void push_front(const T& val) {
        insert(0, val);
    }

    void erase(const size_t idx) {
        bound_check(bound_check_type::GREATER_EQUAL, "List<T>::erase(idx)", idx);

        auto it = begin();
        it.advance(static_cast<int>(idx - 1));

        if(idx != 0) {
            auto it_fwd = it;
            it_fwd.advance(2);
            it.next(it_fwd);
        } else {
            it.advance(1);
            m_root = it.node();
        }

        --m_size;
    }
    void pop_back() {
        erase(m_size - 1);
    }
    void pop_front() {
        erase(0);
    }

    void clear() {
        m_root = nullptr;
        m_size = 0;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t idx) {
        bound_check(bound_check_type::GREATER_EQUAL, "List<T>::operator[](idx)", idx);
        return *begin().advance(idx);
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t idx) const {
        bound_check(bound_check_type::GREATER_EQUAL, "List<T>::operator[](idx) const", idx);
        return *begin().advance(idx);
    }

    iterator_t begin() const {
        return iterator_t{m_root};
    }
    static iterator_t end() {
        return iterator_t{nullptr};
    }

private:
    enum class bound_check_type {
        GREATER, GREATER_EQUAL
    };
    void bound_check(bound_check_type type, std::string func, size_t idx) {
        if(idx > size() || (type == bound_check_type::GREATER_EQUAL && idx == size())) {
            throw std::logic_error{func + ": idx >" + (type == bound_check_type::GREATER ? "" : "=") + " size"};
        }
    }

    shared_ptr_t m_root = nullptr;
    size_t m_size = 0;
};
```

Comment: Side note, by I think this is misguided. Keeping parts of a datastructure alive after it's gone is bound to be problematic at some point. What not use `std::Forward_list` that holds `shared_ptr`s? That way the data can outlive the list, even if the list is dead. You likely want *that* instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You know, your `Node` can be far more general if you don't parameterize with `T` and a template-template, but instead directly with a pointer-to-T.

   > ```
   > template<class T, template<class> class shared_ptr = std::shared_ptr>
   > struct Node {
   >     using shared_ptr_t = shared_ptr<Node<T>>;
   > ```

   Becomes

   ```
   template<class Ptr>
   struct Node {
       using T = typename std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::element_type;
       using shared_ptr_t = typename std::pointer_traits<Ptr>::template rebind<Node<T>>;
   ```
2. Currently, only your `Node` is prepared for using a different pointer-type. You probably want to do `iterator` and `List` up the same.
3. There is no reason for defining the single ctor in `Node`. If you leave it out and use aggregate-initialization instead, you can emplace-construct as needed.
4. The interface of `iterator` should be changed:

   1. `operator==` and `operator!=` should be free functions.
   2. Implicit conversion from `iterator<Ptr<T>>` to `iterator<Ptr<const T>>` should be supported.
   3. `.valid()` is a curious way to ask whether you have a Sentinel. Better rename it `.isEnd()` or such, if you insist on retaining it.
   4. In the same vein, `.insert()` is a bad name as it should be `.insert_after()`. Also, there should be an emplace-variant. If your list supported allocators, it couldn't be a member of the iterator at all.
   5. In the same vein, the exception-message in `.insert()` is non-sensical. It should be `"Cannot insert after the end."`.
   6. `.next()`, aside from the bad name, should not be a member of iterator.
   7. `.advance()` should be a generic algorithm, and most certainly not a member.
   8. You can define `.swap()`. But then it should be `noexcept` and there should be a free-function-variant.
5. You should provide all of the container-interface your implementation of a single-linked-list reasonably can. That means provide const_iterator's, and be consistent with the standards naming.
6. The name `List` suggests it's a generic double-linked list, not a single-linked-list. Call it `forward_list`.
7. You aren't consistent in which conventions you use for types.
8. Your copy-assignment is not self-assignment-safe. Fix it.
9. The size is not updated if the list is changed using an iterator.

I'm stopping my review here, though there are more issues.